# Why doesn't any pointwise convergent imply uniform?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Roughly speaking, the difference between the pointwise convergence and the uniform convergence is the N's dependence on x. So for pointwise convergence in domain $E$:

$$ \exists N \text{ s.t. } |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon \text{ for } n>N, x \in E, \epsilon >0$$

For uniform convergence to work, we add the condition $\forall x$. ie:

$$ \exists N \text{ s.t. } |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon \text{ for } n>N, \forall x \in E, \epsilon >0$$

In the former, N can depend on x, while in the latter, it can only depend on epsilon. The thing is, can't we choose the greatest of all Ns in the former? E.g: if:

$$ |f_n(x_1)-f(x_1)|<\epsilon \implies N\geq 2 $$
$$ |f_n(x_2)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon \implies N\geq 6 $$
$$ |f_n(x_3)-f(x_3)|<\epsilon \implies N\geq 3 $$

can't we choose $N \geq 6$, such that all of the following statements are true? Hence implying uniform convergence?

Comment: You're observing that if you have finitely many $x$ in your domain, then pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence (by choosing the largest $N$). The problem is, if you have infinitely many $x$ in your domain, then there may be no largest $N$ to choose.

Comment: A good counterexample is the sequence $$f_n : x\in [0,1] \mapsto x^n \in \mathbb{R} $$

Comment: It's the quantifiers, mainly. For pointwise read as "for each $x,$ there exists $N$ such that..." versus for uniform "there exists $N$ such that for each $x, \ldots$

Comment: @oliverjones which x in particular should I pick?

Comment: Well every $x$ should be considered, I suggest playing with the sequence of functions I gave to test the two modes of convergence in question.

Comment: I see you have  accepted an answer. Another  counter-example is $f_n:[0,1]\to [0,1]$  where $f_n(x)=x^n$. Then $f_n(x)\to f(x)=0$ for each $x\in [0,1).$ But each $f_n$ is continuous with $f_n(0)=0$ and $f_n(1)=1$, so for each $n$ there exists $x_n\in (0,1)$ with $f_n(x_n)=1/2$. But $f(x_n)=0$.  So for $every$ $n$ there exists some $x$ (that  depends on $n$)  with $|f(x)-f_n(x)|\ge 1/2.$

Comment: I can't make sense of your quantifiers in $ \exists N \text{ s.t. } |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon \text{ for } n>N, x \in E, \epsilon >0$. What does "$\text{ for } n>N, x \in E, \epsilon >0$" mean? You put $n$, $x$ and $\epsilon$ at the end as if they had the same quantifier, but $n$ depends on $N$, and $x$ and $\epsilon$ don't?  This is extremely confusing notation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $E$ consists of finitely many points, then what you're saying works. But generally you will be interested in infinite domains, in which case the maximum you're considering need not exist.

For example, if $E=(0,1]$, and

$$ |f_n(1)-f(1)|<\epsilon \implies N\geq 1 $$
$$ |f_n(1/2)-f(1/2)|<\epsilon \implies N\geq 2 $$
$$ |f_n(1/3)-f(1/3)|<\epsilon \implies N\geq 3 $$
$$ \dots$$
$$ |f_n(1/k)-f(1/k)|<\epsilon \implies N \geq k $$

then there is no single $N$ you can choose that will work for all $x$.